# ^ in package.json dependency version

Tags: node.js, npm

What does the ^ symbol mean in the version of a dependency in package.json?

I couldn't find it in [the docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies).

For example:

```
"dependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.4",
    ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json)

Comment: Couldn't find that because I didn't know what the caret was called

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I found an answer [here](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/02/npm-no-longer-defaults-to-tildes/):

> The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you to the most recent major version (the first number). `^1.2.3` will match any `1.x.x` release including `1.3.0`, but will hold off on `2.0.0`. npm’s [semantic versioning parser](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver) clarifies the distinction:
>
> > ```
> > ~1.2.3 := >=1.2.3-0 <1.3.0-0 "Reasonably close to 1.2.3".
> > ^1.2.3 := >=1.2.3-0 <2.0.0-0 "Compatible with 1.2.3".
> > ```
> >
> > ― isaacs/node-semver (emphasis added)

For completeness, the canonical documentation from the [`semver` repository](https://github.com/npm/node-semver?tab=readme-ov-file#caret-ranges-123-025-004) is as follows:

> ##### Caret Ranges `^1.2.3` `^0.2.5` `^0.0.4`
>
> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero element in the
> `[major, minor, patch]` tuple.  In other words, this allows patch and
> minor updates for versions `1.0.0` and above, patch updates for
> versions `0.X >=0.1.0`, and *no* updates for versions `0.0.X`.
>
> Many authors treat a `0.x` version as if the `x` were the major
> "breaking-change" indicator.
>
> Caret ranges are ideal when an author may make breaking changes
> between `0.2.4` and `0.3.0` releases, which is a common practice.
> However, it presumes that there will *not* be breaking changes between
> `0.2.4` and `0.2.5`.  It allows for changes that are presumed to be
> additive (but non-breaking), according to commonly observed practices.
>
> - `^1.2.3` := `>=1.2.3 <2.0.0-0`
> - `^0.2.3` := `>=0.2.3 <0.3.0-0`
> - `^0.0.3` := `>=0.0.3 <0.0.4-0`
> - `^1.2.3-beta.2` := `>=1.2.3-beta.2 <2.0.0-0` Note that prereleases in
>   the `1.2.3` version will be allowed, if they are greater than or
>   equal to `beta.2`.  So, `1.2.3-beta.4` would be allowed, but
>   `1.2.4-beta.2` would not, because it is a prerelease of a
>   different `[major, minor, patch]` tuple.
> - `^0.0.3-beta` := `>=0.0.3-beta <0.0.4-0`  Note that prereleases in the
>   `0.0.3` version *only* will be allowed, if they are greater than or
>   equal to `beta`.  So, `0.0.3-pr.2` would be allowed.
>
> When parsing caret ranges, a missing `patch` value desugars to the
> number `0`, but will allow flexibility within that value, even if the
> major and minor versions are both `0`.
>
> - `^1.2.x` := `>=1.2.0 <2.0.0-0`
> - `^0.0.x` := `>=0.0.0 <0.1.0-0`
> - `^0.0` := `>=0.0.0 <0.1.0-0`
>
> A missing `minor` and `patch` values will desugar to zero, but also
> allow flexibility within those values, even if the major version is
> zero.
>
> - `^1.x` := `>=1.0.0 <2.0.0-0`
> - `^0.x` := `>=0.0.0 <1.0.0-0`

Comment: Agreed. Maybe bring up an issue on GitHub?